# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-chamber-18560.git'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, version-control

I run these commands

1. heroku create
2. git push heroku master

[image: error information]

Then.

3. git remote add heroku `https://git.heroku.com/radiant-chamber-18560.git`
4. git push heroku master

[image: error information]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you pushed your code to git before trying to push to heroku?

Comment: @angkiki I don't konw...  my  heroku ssH is github.

Comment: im sorry but how can you not know if you have pushed your code to github before trying to push to heroku? the commands are `git add -A` followed by `git commit -m "<insert message here>"` and lastly `git push origin master`

Comment: @angkiki   my application,updated to github.but,I don't know how to update to heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you added and committed your code locally by

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "your commit message"
```

Then try sending you current git `HEAD` to heroku `master` branch instead.

```
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error, it seems Heroku is not being able to detect you are deploying a RoR application. Make sure your `Gemfile` is being sent to Heroku (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure) for more info). You can use @Felipe_Sabino's answer to make sure it is added to git.

Also you could [set the buildpack manually](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application), but it shouldn't be necessary if all files are correct.